# Docker - adding DNS by editing “docker” file

Tags: windows, docker, configuration, dns

I am using Boot2Docker on Windows and I want to edit file **/etc/init.d/docker**. After editing it, saving using **wq** command and **reboot** command its state is not saved. What I am doing wrong? What I want to achieve is to add configurations with DNS like in attached screen (**--bip** and **--dns**):

[image]
Is this right place to do this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems expected, considering [Boot2Docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/) is based on the [TinyCore distro](http://tinycorelinux.net/), which only persists some files in `/var/lib/boot2docker/`

Typically, I modify `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` in order to:

- change other files
- or export (set) other environment variables

That script will be persisted across TinyCore sessions, and will be executed at each restart.

Comment: You mean something like this?

DOCKER_OPTS="--bip=172.167.0.1/16 --dns=10.9.16.1"

Comment: Yes, what you add in that file will be persisted. Use export in order to set that variable to the all session. export DOCKER_OPS=...